# iPhone - NSObject getting reference to viewController

Tags: iphone

I have this object of NSObject class. This object is shown on a view managed by a viewController. How do I get a reference to that viewController from inside the object's class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "myViewController" property as you know. The easiest way to give any object access to some other object is through a delegate relationship.

Define a protocol for the delegate - typically in the module that wants access to the object which will be the delegate, i.e. the view controller

```
@protocol MyViewControllerDelegate

- (void)someActionTheViewControllerWillDo;

#end
```

Advertise the delegate support in the class implementing it

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <MyViewControllerDelegate>
...
@end
```

Implement the function you defined as being part of the protocol in the view controller:

```
@implementation MyViewController

etc. etc.

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark MyViewControllerDelegateMethods

- (void)someActionTheViewControllerWillDo
{
  NSLog(@"I'm being called from an object that has me as a delegate");
}

etc. etc.

@end
```

Make a variable in the calling object to store the delegate object

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
{

etc. etc.

  id<MyViewControllerDelegate> myDelegate;

etc. etc. 
}
```

Initialize that object

```
MyObject* myObject = [[MyObject alloc] initWithblahblah...
myObject.myDelegate = self
/* assuming myObject is being created in the view controller... */
```

In myObject - use the defined protocol to access methods in the delegate object!

```
[myDelegate someActionTheViewControllerWillDo];
```

Comment: I just added a UIViewController property to my NSObject and assigned that to the uiviewcontroller object that initializes my nsobject

Comment: It will work I guess but if you do that every time you want one object to talk to another things will soon get messy and hard to manage.

Answer (score 0):

User delegate pattern:

0 . Declare a protocol:

```
@protocol My_Object_Delegate;
```

1.Give your NSObject an instance variable:

```
id <My_Object_Delegate> delegate;
```

2 . Set this delegate the view controller that supervise it:

```
myObject.delegate = myViewController;
```

3 . When your NSObject is done. Let it ask its delegate to perform certain task:

```
[myObject.delegate performaCertainTask:self];
```